# How to hide status bar in swift 5?

Tags: swift, xcode, hide, statusbar

When I scroll, navigation bar and Status Bar hide
And it works well
But when I go to another page and go back to the first page, navigation bar goes into hiding, but the status bar will not be hidden again.
i want to hide status bar when i scroll . such as navigation bar

this is my code :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var View_Mor: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
}
override var prefersStatusBarHidden : Bool {
    if self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden == true {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

}

```
@IBAction func gotosecondvc(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let st = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = st.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondvc")
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
    present(vc,animated: true,completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is implement this function.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if scrollView.isTracking {   
    // ... perform actions
         //MARK:- Show Status Bar
         UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true
    } else {
    //.. not tracking
        //MARK:- Hide Status Bar
        UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = false
    }
}
```

you can then detect when the user is dragging the scroll view and perform actions based on what it is you want to do and when.

I hope this helps.

Edit———-

```
private var hideStatusBar: Bool = false

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return hideStatusBar
}

override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation {
    return UIStatusBarAnimation.slide
}
```

Usage

```
   func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        if scrollView.isTracking {   
        // ... perform actions
             hideStatusBar = true 
        } else {
        //.. not tracking
            hideStatusBar = false 
        }
    }
```

Comment: how to hide status bar in this func ?

Comment: isStatusBarHidden is deprecated friend ant now working

Comment: @salamanta check my update. Usage was deprecated recently apologizes. Try out my new update